# Hyphenation of “ You ain’t a-kiddin’ ” and such

Tags: hyphenation

In a piece of dialogue, would we use a hyphen after "a" in the phrases "You ain't a-shittin'" and "You ain't a-kiddin'"?

Comment: I would drop the a and hyphen to just be. You ain't shittin. And You ain't kidding.

Comment: @over_optimistic depends on the dialect he's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**.

Hyphenation between the *a* and the *-ing* form of the verb (often spelt as just *-in'* or *-in* in dialect) is the most common way to represent that particular dialectal feature.

While somewhat rare to cause any real confusion given context, minimal pairs are possible:

- It's a-painting. (It is creating an artistic work)
- It's a painting. (It is that artistic work)

The hyphen (*a-painting*) is used instead of just direct prefixing (*apainting*) probably to avoid the weirdness of a double initial *a* in words that start with it (which do get pronounced distinctly when saying something like *he's a-acting*).